# Link2SD: Mount script cannot be created

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, mount, partitions, busybox, ext2

After making a 1744MB ext2 partition on my 4GB MicroSD with the Aparted app (since my Windows SD slot is broken) and trying to select ext2 when I start Link2SD I always get the error:

> Mount script cannot be created
>
> mount: Invalid argument

I tried to delete busybox from system/xbin to install a newer version, but /system won't mount as Read-Write. How do I fix this?

EDIT: I'm using KingRoot

EDIT 2: So I made an ext4 partition instead, and now it says

> Mount script cannot be created
>
> mount: Read-only file system

and I tried running `e2fsck -fpDC0 /dev/block/mmcblk1p2` in terminal emulator ([seen here](http://www.link2sd.info/faq) as a solution)
and I got the output:

`<5> e2fsck:
Internal SD card is not found, now mount manually
<3>e2fsck: save_log_to_file error
/dev/block/mmcblk1p2: |==
/dev/block/mmcblk1p2: |=============================
/dev/block/mmcblk1p2: |=============================`

`/dev/block/mmcblk1p2: 12/116400 files (0.0% non-conti
guous) 16193/465096 blocks`

Comment: Try using ext3 or ext4 filesystem

Comment: It shows up as ext2 in Aparted, and it didn't work in Link2SD when selecting either ext2, 3, or 4.

Comment: EDIT: It's showing up as ext3 now.